# Proof from Lang’s Basic Mathematics

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

Starting on page 11, I don’t understand the proof.

*If $a$, $b$ are negative integers, then $a + b$ is negative.*

Proof. We can write $a = -n$ and $b = -m$, where $m, n$ are positive. Therefore $a + b = -n - m = -(n + m)$,
which shows that $a + b$ is negative, because $n + m$ is positive.

I don’t understand where he says $a$ and $b$ are $-n$ and $-m$, but then $m$ and $n$ are positive. Can anyone explain what is going on?

Comment: Every negative number $x$ is $-y$ where $y$ is positive. (Note if we set $y = -x$ then $x = -y$. And if $x$ is positive, what kind of number is $y$?) Have you thought of examples?

Comment: It often helps to make things concrete.  Let's say $a=-7$ and $b=-390$.  Can you see what $m$ and $n$ are?

Comment: Perhaps it is the way he sets up the question, but I find it confusing.  I thought one way to prove the proposition was to set up the problem as -a + (-b) > 0, to prove by contradiction.  This would mean that -a > b.  Since “a,” as a negative number, cannot be greater than a positive number (“b”), it must be true that (-a) + (-b) is always < 0

Comment: It might be possible to prove it that way (I'm having trouble tracking your proposed argument), but your question asked about understanding the argument presented there.  Does making it concrete in the way I've suggested help you understand the proof presented?

Comment: Not really. Why does he first say a and be are negative numbers, but then he immediately says those numbers are positive?  I’m sure it’s obvious to most, but I don’t understand his proof.

Comment: If $a$ is a negative number, then $-a$ is a positive number; call it $n$. This means $a=-(-a)=-n$, with $n$ positive.

Comment: I understand that a and b are supposed to be the opposite of n and m, so that a + b = (-n) + (-m). 

So if n = 1 and b = 2, then a = -1, and b = -2.  

The opposite of (1 + 2) = -(1 + 2).  So a + b is the same as saying -(n + m). To me, the way I tried to prove the proposition through contradiction makes more sense than this proof.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the hints. I really appreciate it.